# TypeScript and Angular, order of execution in this

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

I have the following code inside an Angular application, the html looks like so.

```
<ng-multiselect-dropdown
    (onSelect)="onSubstringSelect($event)">
</ng-multiselect-dropdown>
```

That `onSubstringSelect` is in the .ts part of the component:

```
onSubstringSelect(item: any) {
    const dataPois = this.getPois(data);
    alert("2nd alert " + dataPois);
    // etc
}
```

---

```
getPois(data): any[] {
    this.api.getPois(data).subscribe((result: any) => {
        alert("1st alert");
        return result.pois;
        }
    }, (error: any) => {
        console.error('error', error);
        return {};
    });

    return null;
}
```

I was expecing that I had first the `alert("1st alert");` and then `alert("2nd alert " + dataPois);`  but that alert is executing first. Why?

Comment: where is `onSubstringSelect` called?

Comment: From an Angular component, I will edit the question

Comment: It doesn't matter where onSubstringSelect 
is called. Subscribe is performed asynchronously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Rx Streams are asynchronous. When you set up your stream, it does indeed set it up; but nothing runs until there's something listening to this. In the Rx world, this is called `subscribing`.

When you hand off your stream to the `AsyncPipe` using `stream$ | async`; it'll subscribe and all the functions within the setup stream will start functioning in order.

This seems counter intuitive at first, but it actually makes a lot of sense. If you want your `console.log` to run in the order you want them, add `tap()` `operators` in order or redefine your stream to match your expectation.

When you do this:

```
function A() {
    const stream$ = this.http.get('my-stream-url').pipe(
            tap(() => { console.log('stream is live!') })
        )
    console.log('But this will show up first, because nothing is listening to the stream$ yet!')
    return stream$
}
```

You can see how the stream will stay stagnant, until someone starts listening to it by `subscribing`.

Comment: So how can I keep working with my code after getting the data of the ajax call? I don't know how to "wait" for the data comming from the API and then keep doing things in my code

Comment: The trick to reactive programming is that you write "all that needs to happen" as a declarative stream. So you either write it as `tap()` side effects and push the Observable down as far you can before actually subscribing. 

In the same spirit, it's maybe easier for you to not manually `subscribe()`, but let Angular take care of it for you. Check out the `AsyncPipe` examples on angular.io.

Answer (score 1):

You do not know when the asynchronous data will be returned. In this case, the answer comes after doing `alert("2nd alert " + dataPois);`.

Comment: is there a way to force the returned data to continue with my code?

Comment: I think that `alert("2nd alert " + dataPois);` return dataPois as undefined

Comment: I would try: ```onSubstringSelect(item: any) {
    getPois.subscribe(
        (result: any) => {
        alert("2nd alert " + dataPois);
        return result.pois;
        }, 
        (error: any) => {
        console.error('error', error);
        return {};
    });
}


getPois(data) {
    return this.api.getPois(data);
}```

Comment: If you want to show `dataPois` you must run `alert("2nd alert " + dataPois);` inside subscribe.